# Undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_url'. Correct syntax in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

wondering if you can help me out.
I'm getting "undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_url'" on sites/new.

Controller is below

```
def create
  @site = Site.find_or_initialize_by_url(params[:site][:url])

  if @site.save
    redirect_to site_path(@site)
  else
    redirect_to :back, :flash => {:error => @site.errors[:url]}
  end
```

What would be the correct syntax for

**@site = Site.find_or_initialize_by_url(params[:site][:url])** in rails 4?

All Code is taken from here https://github.com/blatyo/is_it_popular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 4,it should be

```
@site = Site.find_or_initialize_by(url: params[:site][:url])
```

***Source:*** [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-initialize-by)

Comment: So simple. Thanks Pavan. I'll accept your answer as correct when the time limit allows.